# Comparing UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage

How can I compare an image to another one?

Thanks!

Comment: Compare the pixels or bitmaps to determine if they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two UIImages, you should get their `CGImageRef` quartz representations from those objects. Then create two new bitmap contexts backed by a memory buffer that you create and pass in, one for each of the images. Then use `CGContextDrawImage` to draw the images into the bitmap contexts. Now the bytes of the images are in the buffers. You can then loop through manually or `memcmp` to check for differences.

Apple's own detailed explanation and sample code around creating bitmap contexts and drawing into them is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html

The difference for you is that you're drawing an existing image into the context. Use `CGContextDrawImage` for this.

Comment: Whoaaaa...Thats kinda confusing im not looking for a free ride (i actually want to learn from this) but could you post some code. Im not really framillar with any CG methods..

Or at least try to explain it beter for a noob.

Comment: I've added a link to good info. If it's still a little over your head, check out tutorials and Apple's docs on the basics of Core Graphics. It's too big a subject to answer as a question here on SO, and you need to understand that if you're doing any substantial image work on iOS.

Comment: Erhm That was confusing... Someone said you could just convert it to binary image or just grayscale and compare that. Could I do that?

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what my answer (and the Apple docs) tell you how to do. :) Sorry, but given two UIImages, the only way to compare the pixels directly is to do some nitty-gritty work with Core Graphics contexts. Maybe someone else here will be kind enough to provide complete code for copy and paste.

Comment: meh. The only hard part is I dont know how to find some of the arguments required. (everything except width and height.) I dont mind doing some hard coding.

Comment: Cool, then either update this question, or post a new one asking about the specific arguments you don't understand and how to know what to use for them.

Comment: Im going to put this project on hold, since its more complex than I thought and I have somehting I want to Finish first. I'll ask when Im ready thanks thought!!

Comment: when we go to that above link, it is showing page not found.

Comment: @ArshadShaik What?? A link from 7.5 years ago is no longer valid?! ;) I googled the contents and updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use in my unit tests to compare images. Unlike other methods (e.g., `UIImagePNGRepresentation`), it works even if the images have a different color space (e.g., RGB and grayscale).

```
@implementation UIImage (HPIsEqualToImage)

- (BOOL)hp_isEqualToImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSData *data = [image hp_normalizedData];
    NSData *originalData = [self hp_normalizedData];
    return [originalData isEqualToData:data];
}

- (NSData*)hp_normalizedData
{
    const CGSize pixelSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * self.scale, self.size.height * self.scale);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pixelSize);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, pixelSize.width, pixelSize.height)];
    UIImage *drawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawnImage);
}

@end
```

It's not very efficient, so I would recommend against using it in production code unless performance is not an issue.

Comment: if self is a UIImage, you can directly call UIImagePNGRepresentation on it, without drawing it first. See also [convert UIImage to NSData and back to UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013144/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata-and-back-to-uiimage)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Based on [Skycamelfalling's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514214/skycamefalling) comment, I verified that my unit tests still pass when using UIImage's `pngData()` method, instead of drawing with an image context. Much simpler!

For historic interest: Here is a Swift 4 variant of [hpique's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143378/hpique) answer. It's working for me in my unit tests, when I need to test two UIImages for "sameness".

```
fileprivate extension UIImage {
    func makeNormalizedData() -> Data? {
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        let pixelSize = CGSize(width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pixelSize)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: pixelSize))
        guard let drawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawnImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seem to get the same information as if you just used UIImage.pngData()

Answer (score 2):

here 's code sample

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getImageBinary:(UIImage*)ImageToCompare
{
    int i = 0;    
    int step = 4;

    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    //void * bitmapData;
    //int bitmapByteCount;
    int bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(ImageToCompare.CGImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(ImageToCompare.CGImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow = (pixelsWide * 4);
    NSMutableArray *firstImagearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return nil;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    //bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    //  if (bitmapData == NULL)
    //  {
    //      fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
    //      CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    //      return NULL;
    //  }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits        per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    if (context == NULL)
    {
        //free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{pixelsWide, pixelsHigh}};
    //
    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, ImageToCompare.CGImage);

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    /////**********
    size_t _width = CGImageGetWidth(ImageToCompare.CGImage);
    size_t _height = CGImageGetHeight(ImageToCompare.CGImage);

    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData (context);

    if (data != NULL) 
    {
        int max = _width * _height * 4;

        for (i = 0; i < max; i+=step)
        {
            [firstImagearray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:data[i + 0]]];
            [firstImagearray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:data[i + 1]]];
            [firstImagearray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:data[i + 2]]];
            [firstImagearray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:data[i + 3]]];     }
    }

    if (context == NULL)
        // error creating context
    return nil;


    //if (data) { free(data); }
    if (context) {
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }
    return firstImagearray;
}

-(BOOL)Compare:(UIImage*)ImageToCompare secondImage:(UIImage*)secondImage
{
    ImageToCompare=[ImageToCompare  scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(self.appdelegate.ScreenWidth,self.appdelegate.ScreenHeigth)];
    secondImage=[secondImage scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(self.appdelegate.ScreenWidth, self.appdelegate.ScreenHeigth)];

    NSArray *first=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)[self    getImageBinary:ImageToCompare]];
    NSArray *second=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray *)[self getImageBinary:secondImage]];

    for (int x=0; x<first.count; x++)
    {
        if ([((NSNumber*)[first objectAtIndex:x]) intValue] ==[((NSNumber*)[second objectAtIndex:x]) intValue])
        {

        }
        else
        {
             return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```