# Button's image as a conditional?

Tags: objective-c, image, button, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a conditional that asks about the button's image.
Here's what I have:

```
    if (buttonName.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonImage.png"])
```

This code works fine if the object buttonName is a UIImageView, but as a UIButton, I get the error 'request for member 'image' in something not a structure or union'.

How can I create this conditional?

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks for pointer equality, so generally I would recommend using `isEqual:` which works on `NSObjects`, but this may not work for a `UIImage` (though `UIImage` does inherit from `NSObject` so give it a go).

If that fails, you might try using the `CGImage` property of a `UIImage`. This is the underlying Quartz image data, so you may be able to detect if the two images have the same `CGImage` (again, using `==` will not work, but `isEqual` may).

One way around this is to use the `tag` property of the `UIButton`, but this takes only `int`s, so you'll have to do some re-writing.

Comment: Also, this post is related: [Cocoa Touch - Comparing Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400707/cocoa-touch-comparing-images).

Comment: Comparing the data of two arbitrary images is a reasonably expensive operation; it would be surprising if that was what `isEqual:` did. I'd guess that it's just using the default `NSObject` protocol implementation, which compares the two objects' `hash`es.

Comment: @Josh: Yes, I think comparing pixel for pixel is expensive and probably not worth it. I don't know if `isEqual` will actually work, though. I'd be interested to hear back.

Comment: I actually think I have solved the problem by changing buttonName.image to buttonName.currentImage