# How to compare SKSpriteNode textures

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I am making a game with Sprite Kit.  When there is a collision I would like to retrieve the image of the SKSpriteNode that my projectile collided with to assign different point values depending on the image of the monster.  I think comparing the texture property of the SKSpriteNode could work.  I have tried the following code, but my if statement is never called. Any suggestions?

```
- (void)projectile:(SKSpriteNode *)projectile didCollideWithMonster:(SKSpriteNode *)monster {
        SKTexture *tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"img.png"];
        if ([[monster texture] isEqual:tex])
        {
            NSLog(@"it works");
        }
}
```

Comment: why not to use userData property or name property?

Comment: I specifically want the image of the SKSpriteNode named "monster"

Comment: why not to name different monsters with different names? I think its quite time-consuming to compare two images/textures.

Comment: I tried using monster.name = @"monster1" where I initialize the monster, but still no results when comparing a name in my if statement.

Comment: And? Please, tell us what you want exactly to achieve. Is your SKSpriteNode runs any animations or it has static texture which you want to check and perform some action?

Comment: You should compare strings with isEqualToString: method, not isEqual:

Comment: I am rapidly creating SKSpriteNodes that will move across the screen and are removed when the collision method is called.  When I do a [monster description] on the SKSpriteNode, the only property that is consistent is the SKTexture, that is why I would like to compare the SKTexture of each monster after collision.

Comment: Why do you even call [monster description]?! There is an SKSpriteNode property called "name" and "userData", you should read more about them in Apple docs.

Comment: I know of the "name" and "userData" properties, but what I want to do is retrieve the image of the monster and compare it.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can use UIImage and compare them like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.  Assigning a name actually ended up being my answer.  For some reason I needed to name every monster for it to work, not just one individual.

Comment: @AndrewShmig please post an answer to this question so it can be accepted formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to compare two images/textures using UIImage.

```
- (BOOL)image:(UIImage *)image1 isEqualTo:(UIImage *)image2
{
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);

    return [data1 isEqual:data2];
}
```

Comment: Парень, это ты переводил книгу про CoreData на Хабре? Респект тебе огромный за твой труд! :) Как раз сейчас читаю

Comment: @AndreyGordeev, я :) не закончил правда, но планирую закончить, как только учебу завершу.