# Sprite kit (objective c) check texture of sprite node

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

i need to check if my sprite node texture is equal to name @"GoldDot".
i try the code

```
if ([red.texture isEqual:@"GoldDot"]) {

     NSLog(@"gold!!!!");
    }else{



}
```

please help

Comment: You are comparing an `SKTexture` to a `NSString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare SKTextures, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23217130/2043580).

A cleaner alternative would be to set the name of the SKSpriteNode as the image you are setting.

```
NSString *textureName = @"GoldDot";
SKSpriteNode *node =[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: textureName];
node.name = textureName;
```

Afterwards, just compare the name

```
if ([red.name isEqual:@"GoldDot"]) {
   NSLog(@"gold!!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you would be better testing to see if your texture is equal to another texture, not a string. The test you might want to try is,

```
if([red.texture isEqual:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"GoldDot.png"]]){
     NSLog(@"gold!!!");
else{
}
```

Then simply give the name of the texture you are looking for.

Comment: This probably wouldnt work. A separate texture instance, even though derived fromt the same image will not return equal using that method.