# Swift: if statement to check if Node Texture is the same as another Node texture

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, textures

There are 5 balls with different colors. The choiceBall changes randomly textures(colors) with each tap and indicates which of the other 4 colored balls you have to tap on. I thought of doing an if statement where I check if the ball that I tapped on is the same texture as the choiceBall but I can't seem to find a way that works.

Here I thought if choiceBall turns red and I press the red ball that RED would be printed. But it doesn't seem to happen. Shouldn't I be in touchesBegan since I want RED or BLUE or YELLOW or GREEN to be printed every time I *tap* on a ball.

Thanks for any help. :)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    choiceBall.texture = array[randomIndex]


    if choiceBall.texture == redBall.texture {
        println("RED")
    }
    else if choiceBall.texture == blueBall.texture
    {
        println("BLUE")
    }
    else if choiceBall.texture == yellowBall.texture {
        println("YELLOW")
    }
    else if choiceBall.texture == greenBall.texture {
        println("GREEN")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**this answer on another StackOverflow post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23217130/5099203) for the solution you're probably looking for.

In terms of game architecture, I would recommend using an enum of `Color` (or something similar) on `choiceBall`, because then you won't be comparing the actual textures, just the type of `Color` each ball is. It'll make for more cleaner code, and you'll probably be able to squeeze some more functionality out of that as well.

**Example:**

```
enum Color {
    case Red, Blue, Yellow, Green
}

[...]

if choiceBall.colorType == .Red {
    println("RED")
}
else if choiceBall.colorType == .Blue {
    println("BLUE")
}
else if choiceBall.colorType == .Yellow {
    println("YELLOW")
}
else if choiceBall.colorType == .Green {
    println("GREEN")
}
```