# Loop Until Two Objects/Images Don't Match

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, loops

I'm having trouble with loops.  I have one `imageView` which displays an artist's image and another `imageView` which I would like to display artwork of a random song.  BUT, **this artwork must not match the artist image**.  *[To clear things up - the artist image is one of the song's artwork]*.

I'd like to essentially write this in Objective-C for iPhone:

> Do {
>
> Get artwork of random song in `songsArray`
>
> Until{
>
> image1 != image2;
>
> }

This is what I've tried so far (`firstArtwork` is the artist's image and `secondArtwork` is the randomly-chosen artwork that **must not be the same as `firstArtwork`**).

```
-(UIImage *)getSecondImage{

    MPMediaItemArtwork *firstArtwork = [self.mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    // Choose random song in songsArray + get Artwork

    MPMediaItem *myItem = [songTracks objectAtIndex:arc4random() % songsArray.count];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *secondArtwork = [myItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    // Get images

    UIImage *firstImage = [firstArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    UIImage *secondImage = [secondArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

    // IF the two images are the same, repeat this block  
    // IF NOT, return secondImage

    if ([firstImage isEqual:secondImage]){
        [self getSecondImage];
    }
    else{
    return secondImage;
    }

    return secondImage;
}
```

But this sometimes returns an image that's the same as the artist's image.

I've also tried using an `NSPredicate` but I get the error that you can't filter using the MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork.... so I can't use a preciate.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this logically/the correct way. Can anybody help me out and explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `return` value. Note that your `if` statement that checks the value of the 2 images doesn't actually change anything that gets returned to the initial method invoker. Also, your `else` statement is useless because whether or not your `if` statement is true, it will then return `secondImage`. You need to do something like this:

```
if ([firstImage isEqual:secondImage]){
    secondImage = [self getSecondImage];
}

return secondImage;
```

This way, you update the value that is returned to the initial invoker.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I loaded the view a few times and secondImage was the same as firstImage a few times.  Also, I added an `NSLog(@"firstImage isEqual to secondImage");` to the `if` statement, and it didn't show even though firstImage was equal to secondImage.  :S

Comment: Have you tried comparing the `MPMediaItemArtwork` objects instead of the `UIImage`s?

Comment: The same thing happens - same image appears and the NSLog doesn't show.. I don't understand what's happening :S

Comment: Have you tried something like this to compare your images instead of the built-in `isEqual:`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: your pseudo-code is correct (a simple loop), but your implementation contains recursion, which is an unnecessary complexity in this case IMO (and seems that you're not quite sure what you're doing).

```
-(UIImage *)getSecondImage{

    MPMediaItemArtwork *firstArtwork = [self.mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    UIImage *firstImage = [firstArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
    UIImage *secondImage = nil;
    do {
        // Choose random song in songsArray + get Artwork

        MPMediaItem *myItem = [songTracks objectAtIndex:arc4random() % songsArray.count];
        MPMediaItemArtwork *secondArtwork = [myItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

        // Get image

        secondImage = [secondArtwork imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];

        // IF the two images are the same, repeat this loop
        // IF NOT, return secondImage
    } while ([firstImage isEqual:secondImage]);
    return secondImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but after a few tries the second image was the same as the first image on a few occassions.  :S

Comment: then probably you need to find some other way to compare two `UIImage` objects rather than `-isEqual:`