# Comparing image views in iOS 8 not working

Tags: xcode, image, button, imageview, ios8

I am using a button with multiple image view, for example after clicking on the button the image of that button change so i used something like that:

```
if(button.imageVIew.image ==[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriendPressed.png"]){

    do something

}
```

This was working in iOS 7 and not iOS8.
Any solutions please?

---

```
- (BOOL)image:(UIImage *)image1 isEqualTo:(UIImage *)image2
{
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);

    return [data1 isEqual:data2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **isEqual** :

```
if([button.imageVIew.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriendPressed.png"]]){
    do something
}
```

or

```
if([[button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual: [UIImage imageNamed:@"addFriendPressed.png"]]){
    do something
}
```

or [add a category to UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects)