# When I press iPhone home button, sleep/power button or terminate my app, and rerun it again, The TestButtonAction don't print

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I made a simple code to clarify my problem. When I run my app on my iPhone it works properly, but when I press home button - either on simulator or my real iPhone - and press the app icon again, the app runs, but the app's button "TestButtonAction don't work. Same problem when I press power/sleep button and turn it on again.
same problem either when I duple click home button and terminate my app by sliding it's window away, and rerun it again the button don't work or print "Right Image" in the Console
Here is my code, Thanks.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestingHomeButton
//
//  Created by Samuel Oncy on 4/25/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Samuel Oncy. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var TestButtonOutlet: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func TestButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(TestButtonOutlet.imageView?.image == UIImage(named:"NatureView")){
                    print("Right Image")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean                     print("Right Image")
 is not printing in console?

Comment: yes, this is a simple version of my code but it don't work too.

Comment: It seems, your Image has issue, or some other layer is coming in front. If code is very simply, you can share/compress and upload, i will see, issue and reply

Comment: I tried some other photos put the same problem, the code is very simple it's just like what i wrote above

Comment: Remove Photo condition, 

        if(TestButtonOutlet.imageView?.image == UIImage(named:"NatureView")){


This one, remove it, as you need click, why this condition in between here

Comment: I use this code and run my app: print(TestButtonOutlet.imageView?.image == UIImage(named:"NatureView"))      it prints True in the console but when i press home button and run app again it prints false

Comment: Is it coming inside IBAction?

Comment: yes.. I'm trying to upload my code but i don't know how because I'm new on StackOverflow

Comment: you can try create a new project and create button inside the view. then assign a photo for it called for instance NatureView. and create outlet and action for the button like my previous code and please let me know if this problem appears, thanks

Comment: Its no issue here, seems you have something in code, not explained here, you can share code/project zip.

Comment: Sorry, where can i find "share code project zip", I pressed the edit button and found code button but there is no project zip in it.

Comment: You can upload to dropbox and share, or gmail and share link.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhlyv2od15tzc8q/TestingHomeButton.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please check answer.

Comment: Refer to link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: You should compare image data in order to check if two images are equal or not

Comment: ok, thanks so much Vikky I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Make UIImage global Variable, If you want to compare in If.

Other ways can also be to solve same problem - Tag is right one.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var TestButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    var image = UIImage (named: "NatureView")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func TestButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

       // print(TestButtonOutlet.imageView?.image == UIImage(named:"NatureView"))
        if (TestButtonOutlet.currentImage == image) {
            print(TestButtonOutlet.currentImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Job.. Well Done bro. :)

Comment: sorry there is related issue.. when I duple click home button and terminate the app window by sliding it away, and rerun the app again the same issue appears!!!

Comment: I will look into it, in couple of hours, than back to you.

Comment: Thanks os much bro., please let me know if I should create a new thread for the issue of "rerun terminated app"?

Comment: I guide you to tell me, what is your requirement, so I can tell your better way to identify, than matching images.

Comment: i made 2 image buttons with default images. and a button read image's names and do a lot of thing such as.. if the image1 is Red and the other one is yellow do something.  and by pressing these two images their their own images changes so if I press the main button, it compares these images and do different functions. either if I press anyone of the 2 imageButtons and their colors changes they're also do something after touch inside event happens.. I know it's so complicated but to be simple for the user, thanks :)

Comment: I'll consider this question answers and create another one with the other issue .. thanks so much for your help you solved 90% of my problem

Comment: When you killing the APP, its removed from XCode Debugger, so Its no more able to show you LOGs, 

So, you can do is put a LABEL and change its text, instead of showing LOGs.

Answer (score 0):

To check the current image of button, use the `currentImage` property as follows:-

```
@IBAction func TestButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "NatureView")) {
        print("Right Image")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I tried this code now it's running but when i press the  home button and rerun my app again the button don't work and don't print anything

Comment: On returning to the app, print the current image of your button and check what it is printing in console.

Comment: print nothing but when i remove the condition and run my app. it print true , and when i press the home button and rerun my app again it prints false

Comment: Optional(<UIImage: 0x6040000b0020>, {120, 160})

Comment: current image prints the previous line but after using home button, don't print anything

Comment: Hit & Trial:- There may be some issue with your `IBOutlet`. So try to update the `TestButtonOutlet` with `sender, as I did in my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021286/988169)

Comment: it fixes your uploaded code to this one: if (sender as AnyObject).currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "NatureView")) {
            print("Right Image")
        }

Comment: when i press the UIbutton for the first time it gives me a long error this is the end of error code: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: this is the project link if you'd like to check it, Thanks so much