# How to recognize or match two images?

Tags: ios, arkit, image-recognition, coreml

I have one image stored in my bundle or in the application.
Now I want to scan images in camera and want to compare that images with my locally stored image. When image is matched I want to play one video and if user move camera from that particular image to somewhere else then I want to stop that video.

For that I have tried [Wikitude sdk for iOS](https://www.wikitude.com/download-wikitude-sdk-for-ios/) but it is not working properly as it is crashing anytime because of memory issues or some other reasons.

Other things came in mind that [Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml) and [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/) but Core ML detect the image's properties like name, type, colors etc and I want to match the image. ARKit will not support all devices and ios and also image matching as per requirement is possible or not that I don't have idea.

If anybody have any idea to achieve this requirement they can share. every help will be appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: ARKit definitely seems like the way to go. Yes, limited on devices, however, the iPhone 6S and up can run them. More than not, the majority of people will be iPhone 6S and up. I'd definitely be running ARKit

Comment: What about 
vuforia    ?

Comment: @impression7vx : Any link or example related to the requirement based on arkit?

Comment: Like you want that `UIImage` matches with given part when rotating camera or you are searching to compare exact looing two `UIImage`'s?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon : yes something like exact looking image!

Comment: @Lion I don't think so, this will help or not, but here is nice answer provided by Vlad (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects) and proposed by Facebook.

Comment: Just look up Swift ARKit Image Detection. This is what ARKit is for

Comment: @Lion I think you need to scan the image and check whether the certain object in the frame is similar to the object which you have in the asset. CoreML produce something like a confidence score for how well image A matches image B, where image A and image B are two arbitrary photos. So You can use confidence interval to check the image is correct or not. For Better output You can train your own CoreML model

Comment: @Ruban4Axis `CoreML` need `mlmodel` for comparing but he only has one `UIImage` in Bundle and based on that he wants to compare.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon He knows what is the image he have in the asset right ? He can put the Labels for each image what is in the asset. Using mlmodel he can detect and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is ARKit's `imageDetection`. You know the limitation of devices it support. But the result it gives is wide and really easy to implement. [Here is an example](https://hackernoon.com/playing-videos-in-augmented-reality-using-arkit-7df3db3795b7)

Next is CoreML, which is the hardest way. You need to understand machine learning even if in brief. Then the tough part - training with your dataset. Biggest drawback is you have single image. I would discard this method.

Finally mid way solution is to use OpenCV. It might be hard but suit your need. You can find different methods of feature matching to find your image in camera feed. [example here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html). You can use objective-c++ to code in c++ for ios.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is image similarity you can do it simply and with more reliable output results using machine learning. Since your task is using camera scanning. Better option is CoreML.You can refer this [link](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/master/userguide/image_similarity/README.md) by apple for Image Similarity.You can optimize your results by training with your own datasets. Any more clarifications needed comment.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a so-called "siamese network". Which really means that you use a model such as Inception-v3 or MobileNet and both images and you compare their outputs.

However, these models usually give a classification output, i.e. "this is a cat". But if you remove that classification layer from the model, it gives an output that is just a bunch of numbers that describe what sort of things are in the image but in a very abstract sense.

If these numbers for two images are very similar -- if the "distance" between them is very small -- then the two images are very similar too.

So you can take an existing Core ML model, remove the classification layer, run it twice (once on each image), which gives you two sets of numbers, and then compute the distance between these numbers. If this distance is lower than some kind of threshold, then the images are similar enough.