# Stop the code if the if statement ist true SWIFT

Tags: swift, if-statement

im Sorry I´m a litte rusty in coding and i couldn't figure this out.
He goes through all the colors till he es back again on blue.
After a If statement is true he shouldn't look for the next one. Thanks for your understanding...

```
@IBAction func didTapLike(){
    
    
    if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "blue"){
        profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "yellow")
    }
   
    if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "yellow"){
        profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "green")
    }
    
    if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "green"){
        profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "purple")
    }
   
    if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "purple"){
        profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "red")
    }
    
    if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "red"){
        profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "blue")
    }
    
    else {
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Add `return` after each `profileImage.image = newImage`, or use `else if` instead of consecutive `if` (which can also be written with a `switch`)...

Comment: You are probably going to get caught by this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects Comparing the `UIImage` is probably not the route you want to take.

Comment: Comparing did work but the whole loop doesent.

Comment: Bad idea to compare image references. Even if compare works for you at this moment, one day you will shoot in your leg. Use suggested solution instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399150/1135154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more efficient solution is array based.

In the function the index is incremented.
If the number of items in the array is exceeded the index is reset to 0 by the modulo (`%`) operator

```
var colorIndex = 0

@IBAction func didTapLike() {
   let colorArray = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "purple", "red"]
   colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colorArray.count
   profilImage.image = UIImage(named: colorArray[colorIndex])
}
```

On setup you have to set the image to `blue` or the index to the corresponding value of the default color.

Answer (score 1):

Hy use else if, it will be better

```
    @IBAction func didTapLike(){
    
        if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "blue") {
            profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "yellow")
        } else if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "yellow") {
            profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "green")
        } else if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "green") {
            profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "purple")
        } else if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "purple") {
            profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "red")
        } else if profilImage.image == UIImage(named: "red") {
            profilImage.image = UIImage(named: "blue")
        } else {  
        }   
    }
```