# imageview empty after going out of app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've created some code to display a image in a imageview when the current image is equal to a certain imageview. It works correctly but If I decide to go out of the app and then back in it somehow doesn't see the current image and the comparison doesn't work anymore.

```
if (imageview25.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUEBOXPUNT.png"]){
            key25.hidden = NO;
        }
```

So this works but when I leave app and come back in it doesn't see that the image is equal to BLUEBOXPUNT.png

Is there a other way to do this or to do something like in Java I would do imageview25.getImage. I think that would work.

Comment: Interesting.  You recognize, though that although the visible image `imageview25.image` and `[UIImage imageNamed:@"BLUEBOXPUNT.png"]` look the same to the eye, you are comparing pointers to a `UIImage` and those pointers may not (are probably not) the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison logic is checking whether two image objects have the same address.  This will only work while the image remains in cache.  It's likely that a memory warning will cause the same problem you see when switching apps.

If you want to associate images and their file names, I think you'll need to do it yourself, possibly with a dictionary that is keyed to the names.

Comment: I created booleans to be true when A image has become BLUEBOXPUNT since they will remember the boolean, do you think this is a 'ok' way to fix my problem?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without knowing the program logic but it sounds reasonable.  It fits with the principle of keeping your own indicator of what it is you want to test.

Comment: Alright thank you for your answer and your clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show more than one image. An easier way is to use more than one `UIImageView`, all are the same size and at the same place. But each show a different image. Then you can show the one you need and hide others(or `bringSubviewToFront`).

If you indeed need to compare two image:

[Cocoa Touch - Comparing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3400863/1548523)

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)